# "Unresolved reference: Parcelize" after updating to Kotlin 1.3.30

Tags: android, kotlin

I was using Kotlin 1.3.21 for a long time together with `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin in experimental mode for a long time. Today I swtiched to Kotlin 1.3.30 just by bumping the version and now wherever I used `@Parcelize` annotation I see the error:
`Unresolved reference: Parcelize`.

Here's how I enable android extensions:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
    features = ["parcelize"]
}
```

Notice, that I tried without explicitly declaring required features and it didn't work as well.

Also notice that I use Grrovy Gradle DSL.

How can I enable `Parcelize`back with Kotlin 1.3.30?

**EDIT** Here's my app level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "de.mannodermaus.android-junit5"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply from: "../versions.gradle"

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.dtt"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
    }

    testOptions {
        junitPlatform {
            filters {
                engines {
                    include 'spek2'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

detekt {
    input = files("src/main/kotlin")
    baseline = file("detekt-baseline.xml")
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
    features = ["parcelize"]
}

dependencies {
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerview_version"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint_layout_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rx_java_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rx_android_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:$rx_kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"

    debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:$leak_canary_version"
    releaseImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$leak_canary_version"

    testImplementation "org.spekframework.spek2:spek-dsl-jvm:$spek_version"
    testImplementation "org.spekframework.spek2:spek-runner-junit5:$spek_version"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_jupiter_version"
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:$mockk_version"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_jupiter_version"
}
```

Comment: can you please post your gradle?

Comment: @android added to the edit section.

Comment: i can be able to successfully use "parcelize" in my gradle as well in i can be able to also use parcelize annotation. i think you should add this dependency in your app level gradle,   implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.30"

Comment: @android I already have implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.30". As I said all was working until I bumped version to 1.3.30

Comment: i can be able to use it however with 1.3.30.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I find the error

`Kotlin plugin should be enabled before 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

so change the order to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

it work fine *(:з」∠)* 。

good luck to you.

Comment: lol, android studio creates it wrong by default, I have been scratching my head until I saw your answer

Comment: It's easy to miss a bug in code that was generated by an official tool... lol.

Comment: `kotlin-android-extensions`  plugin is deprecated you should implement  `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.7.10"` insted.

Answer (score 10):

### Latest kotlin version requires this plugin to use `@Parcelize`:

```
id 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

or for gradle.kts

```
id("kotlin-parcelize")
```

Comment: Kotlin DSL

1) root/app/build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("kotlin-parcelize") <-- add this
}

2) import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded Kotlin plugin to latest version (1.3.61) and this error was removed.