# androidExtensions "parcelize" not work in Kotlin 1.3.30

Tags: android, kotlin

it work fine with  `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'`

Unresolved reference: Parcelize” after updating to Kotlin 1.3.30

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
    features = ["parcelize"]
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772345/unresolved-reference-parcelize-after-updating-to-kotlin-1-3-30

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I find the error

`Kotlin plugin should be enabled before 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

so change the order to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

it work fine (:з」∠) 。

good luck to you.

Comment: Works for me Thanks a lot!!